# How can you set the default behaviour of all imageviews to change alpha on click in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I am working on an already developed application and wish to make it look more responsive

The previous developer used a large number of imageviews instead of buttons with just a src drawable

This means that when the user presses the imageviews they get no feedback that they pressed it

Now what I would normally do is create a selector with the alpha set to 'f' when not pressed and maybe '8' when pressed

Unfortunatelly the number of imageviews and drawables is quite large

Is there a way to set the default behaviour of all ImageViews in my theme so that when they are pressed they change their alpha?

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Can you tell something more about the problem? Like what language are we talking about? Framework etc? Maybe an example? Difficult to answer like this.

Comment: You should try something yourself before asking someone else as per rules - [mcve] In any case I would suggest not fixing one mess with a more complex mess. Imagine maintaining it later.

Comment: Have you tried for ripple effect?  set this property in your imagView `android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` this is better than alpha

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not fixing one mess with a more complex mess. Imagine maintaining it later. If you are adamant on doing it, I suggest adding the following instead (to add the material design touch ripple reaction)

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

In the theme that will be

```
<item name="android:foreground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
```

But if you want to fix it properly for futures sake you could replace ImageViews with ImageButtons that use the current src.